# Spring Boot logs out after custom error page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application with HttpSecurity, which looks like the following.

*Code*

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()  
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()          
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**").denyAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/uploads")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll();               
}
```

I have added a custom error page (403) as displayed on the [docs.spring.io website](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-error-handling-custom-error-pages) (the file structure).

Last, I created a small 403.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" layout:decorator="layout/main">

<body>
    <div layout:fragment="content">
        <h1>403 - Permission Denied</h1>     

        <p>You do not have permission to retrieve the URL or link you requested.</p>

        <p>Please contact the administrator of the referring page, if you think this was a mistake.</p>

        <p>If you did this on purpose: behave and go back to the <a href="/adminconsole/">Homepage</a>.</p>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This works: If a user is logged in and tries to access a /admin/ page, he will see the custom 403 page.

*Problem*

But the user is also logged out, for some reason! If I change the URL from the Access Denied page to /user/uploads (which I'm allowed to see as a logged in user), it will redirect me back to the login page.

*Question*

How can I make sure that the user isn't logged out when s/he sees the custom 403 page?

**EDIT**

Added the Spring Security debug log. It consists of 3 actions:

- Log in to the website
- Going to a forbidden /admin/users.html page
- Clicking the 'homepage' link in the custom 403 page

Log:

```
2017-06-13 14:55:41.874  INFO 7144 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/static/js/passwordChanging.js':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@146c683

servletPath:/static/js/passwordChanging.js
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
accept: */*
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
referer: http://localhost:8080/adminconsole/
cookie: JSESSIONID=F690AA15EEAAF2DC9BD35E7CCFA5E94F
connection: keep-alive


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2017-06-13 14:55:41.879  INFO 7144 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/static/js/login.js':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@108c693

servletPath:/static/js/login.js
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
accept: */*
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
referer: http://localhost:8080/adminconsole/
cookie: JSESSIONID=F690AA15EEAAF2DC9BD35E7CCFA5E94F
connection: keep-alive


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2017-06-13 14:55:41.964  INFO 7144 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/static/js/utils.js':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@108c693

servletPath:/static/js/utils.js
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
accept: */*
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
referer: http://localhost:8080/adminconsole/
cookie: JSESSIONID=F690AA15EEAAF2DC9BD35E7CCFA5E94F
connection: keep-alive


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************
```

Comment: @dur, I added the debug info!

Comment: Worked it out: needed to add isUserLoggedInfo() in the `model`.